# Create a view using multiple models data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, link-to

My (rails 3) application use `collection` and `product` as models. collection `has_many` products and product `belongs_to` collection.

I managed to have interactions between products and models. I created a menu displaying the different collection. I want to display a view showing only the product belonging to a specific collection.

1) Is it more elegant to create a new view/controller, or do i create a new view in the product views

2)It seems that i must do something with the routes.rb, but how and what?

3)What link_to arguments must i use to pass the value of my collection?

4)I read a whole book (pragmatic ROR) and depspite that and doing a lot of online research i keep ending here asking for not so much complicated Rails question. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would go with creating new action in collection controllers. Url will look like this:

   /collections/1/products

   where 1 is collection id.
2. I assume you have

   resources collections

   so you need to add 'products' action for collection member:

   ```
   resources collections do
     member do
       get :products
     end
   end
   ```

   You can run rake routes from console to see how your application routes look now.
3. Link code should look like this

   ```
   link_to "Collection products", products_collection_path(@collection)
   ```
4. In my opinion reading is ok, but while you read you should do lots of examples, write them yourself, becouse otherwise you forget stuff very quickly. I'm 100% sure that stuff I wrote above was in the book you've read.

Comment: In fact i am modifying the app that is develloped through all the book.
How should i call the new erb?

Comment: products.html.erb and place it in /app/view/controllers